# VerificationException when setting readonly fields (C#)

Tags: c#, reflection, setter, anonymous-types, verificationexception

I am trying to write code that can set arbitrary fields on caller-provided objects which may include anonymous ones. Creating delegates is not possible (Expression compiler realizes that anonymous objects' fields are readonly), so I chose to emit some IL.
However, when doing this I am running into VerificationException ("Operation could destabilize he runtime").
The same simple code runs just fine on objects with regular fields. Fails on readonly fields. 
What else could be done here?
I am running .Net 4.6.2.

Thanks in advance!

```
class TestRegular
{
    private string field;
}

class TestReadOnly
{
    private readonly string field;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Verify(new TestRegular());     // this works
        Verify(new TestReadOnly());    // this does not work
        Verify(new { field = "abc" }); // this does not work
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    private static void Verify<T>(T test)
    {
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Action <T, object> setter = CompileSetter<T>(fields[0]);
        setter(test, "value");
    }

    private static Action<TResult, object> CompileSetter<TResult>(FieldInfo field)
    {
        string methodName = field.ReflectedType.FullName + ".TestSetter";
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, null, new[] { typeof(TResult), typeof(object) }, true);
        ILGenerator gen = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, field.FieldType);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<TResult, object>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TResult, object>));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is absolutely in line with the specs. Have a look at the [ECMA-335 Section II.16.1.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2324%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C535%2C0%5D):

> **initonly**
>   marks fields which are constant after they are initialized. These fields shall only be mutated 
>   inside a constructor. If the field is a static field, then it shall be mutated only inside the type initializer 
>   of the type in which it was declared. If it is an instance field, then it shall be mutated only in one of the 
>   instance constructors of the type in which it was defined. It shall not be mutated in any other method or 
>   in any other constructor, including constructors of derived classes.
>
> [
>   Note:
>    The use of 
>   ldflda
>    or 
>   ldsflda
>    on an 
>   initonly
>    field makes code **unverifiable**.
>     In unverifiable code, 
>   the VES need not check whether 
>   initonly
>    fields are mutated outside the constructors. The VES need 
>   not report any errors if a method changes the value of a constant. However, **such code is not valid**. 
>   end 
>   note
>   ]

To handle this case gracefully you can use the [FieldInfo.IsInitOnly Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_FieldInfo_IsInitOnly).